# My app does not show if statement in browser

Tags: python, html, django

My app does not show if statement in browser.
I wrote in tc.html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Score</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Score</h1>
    <h2>Your Score is
    　{{ tcresults.tc }}
      {{ value1 = tcresults.tc
         if value1 > 5000:
       　 <h2>Good</h2>
        　elseif value1 < 900:
          <h2>Bad</h2>
       }}

    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanna show in my app's browser,
if users' score is bigger than 5000,I wanna show "Good" in my browser and users' score is smaller than 900,I wanna show "Bad" in my browser.
But now, all my if statement is showed in  my app's browser.
Data base has users' tcresults datas.
How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django templates conditions and loops are written in `{% conditions/loops %}`

While variables are written in `{{ variables }}`

Documents https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#if

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Score</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Score</h1>
    <h2>Your Score is
    　{% with tcresults.tc as value1 %}

     {% if value1 > 5000 %}
       　 <h2>Good</h2>
       {% else value1 < 900 %}
          <h2>Bad</h2>

       {% endif %}
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```